# Rails: insert query : missing columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using rails 4.0 for my development. I have create a blog model with two fields: title and content.

Here is my model file:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: blogs
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string(255)
#  content    :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content
  attr_accessor :title, :content
end
```

here is my database migration:

```
class CreateBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :blogs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :content

      # create magic column created_at and updated_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have used rails sandbox console for testing.

```
b = Blog.new
b.title = "blog"
b.content = "blog"
b.save # return true
```

then console notice me:

```
INSERT INTO "blogs" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-08 04:44:40.966670"], ["updated_at", "2014-11-08 04:44:40.966670"]]
```

That means insert query misses title and content field. I don't know how to debug and see where this query generate. Also I don't know how to fix this bug. Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you want to debug it yourself, try using the byebug gem: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `Blog` model and `attr_accessor` statement. In short, it adds getter and setter for these two fields and overrides default `ActiveRecord` behaviour. Just remove it and you'll see that it works.

Also, there's no need to add `attr_accessible :title, :content` because since Rails 4, [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) are used.

Comment: thanks :) I have fixed it :D i'm new comer of rails. I'm reading `Ruby on Rails tutorial 3` to model section. author has said that put `attr_accessor` before any fields to make virtual attribute, atrribute that not store in database. :D I can understand now :)

Comment: and with your explanation, i can understand why :)